# How do I get jQuery to ignore hidden elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, hidden

I know this is bad, because most of y'all like seeing the code on here.
However I'm trying to make an extensive calculator for my small business and I'm doing a lot of things wrong.

Please don't correct all my code, that would be too much work. But I was wondering if there is a way to not run jQuery on an element when it is hidden.

I have several calculators for each product type and the way my code is written, it only works on that first element ID even when it is hidden.

Here is a link to the calculator I'm working on: http://www.virtualbookworm.com/productioncalcnew.php

and here is the JS: http://www.virtualbookworm.com/vbwcalcnew.js

Comment: Sorry, but posting the relevant code in your question *isn't* optional. You may have to create a [small, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org), but that's a good idea *anyway*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to select elements that aren't hidden in a selector, the simple solution is to use the `:visible` selector.

For example :

```
var inputs = $('input:visible');
```

Comment: Worth noting that [this won't count elements that have `display:block` but `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0`, since they still consume space in the layout.](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) However, this doesn't apply to the OP's code.